# More efficient solution on coding task using Stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream

I recently had a technical interview and got small coding task on Stream API.
Let's consider next input:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private List<String> subjects;
    //getters and setters
}

Student stud1 = new Student("John", Arrays.asList("Math", "Chemistry"));
Student stud2 = new Student("Peter", Arrays.asList("Math", "History"));
Student stud3 = new Student("Antony", Arrays.asList("Music", "History", "English"));

Stream<Student> studentStream = Stream.of(stud1, stud2, stud3);
```

The task is to **find Students with unique subjects using Stream API**.
So for the provided input expected result (ignoring order) is `[John, Anthony]`.

I presented the solution using custom Collector:

```
Collector<Student, Map<String, Set<String>>, List<String>> studentsCollector = Collector.of(
        HashMap::new,
        (container, student) -> student.getSubjects().forEach(
                subject -> container
                        .computeIfAbsent(subject, s -> new HashSet<>())
                        .add(student.getName())),
        (c1, c2) -> c1,
        container -> container.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() == 1)
                .map(e -> e.getValue().iterator().next())
                .distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
);
List<String> studentNames = studentStream.collect(studentsCollector);
```

But the solution was considered as not optimal/efficient.
Could you please share your ideas on more efficient solution for this task?

**UPDATE:** I got another opinion from one guy that he would use reducer (Stream.reduce() method).
But I cannot understand how this could increase efficiency. What do you think?

Comment: Will post my solution shortly,now in train btw thanks for the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another one.

```
// using SimpleEntry from java.util.AbstractMap
Set<Student> list = new HashSet<>(studentStream
    .flatMap(student -> student.getSubjects().stream()
        .map(subject -> new SimpleEntry<>(subject, student)))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (l, r) -> Student.SENTINEL_VALUE)
    .values());
list.remove(Student.SENTINEL_VALUE);
```

<sup>(Intentionally using a sentinel value, more about that below.)</sup>

The steps:

1. ```
   Set<Student> list = new HashSet<>(studentStream
   ```

   We're creating a HashSet from the Collection we're going to collect. That's because we want to get rid of the duplicate students (students with multiple unique subjects, in your case Antony).
2. ```
   .flatMap(student -> student.subjects()
       .map(subject -> new SimpleEntry(subject, student)))
   ```

   We are flatmapping each student's subjects into a stream, but first we map each element to a pair with as key the subject and as value the student. This is because we need to retain the association between the subject and the student. I'm using `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`, but of course, you can use any implementation of a pair.
3. ```
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (l, r) -> Student.SENTINEL_VALUE)
   ```

   We are collecting the values into a map, setting the subject as key and the student as value for the resulting map. We pass in a third argument (a `BinaryOperator`) to define what should happen if a key collision takes place. **We cannot pass in `null`, so we use a sentinel value<sup>1</sup>**.
   At this point, we have inverted the relation student ↔ subject by mapping each subject to a student (or the `SENTINEL_VALUE` if a subject has multiple students).
4. ```
   .values());
   ```

   We take the values of the map, yielding the list of all students with a unique subject, plus the sentinel value.
5. ```
   list.remove(Student.SENTINEL_VALUE);
   ```

   The only thing left to do is getting rid of the sentinel value.

---

<sup>1</sup> We cannot use `null` in this situation. Most implementations of a Map make no distinction between a key mapped to `null` or the absence of that particular key. Or, more accurately, the merge method of `HashMap` [actively removes a node](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l1253) when the remapping function returns `null`. If we want to avoid a sentinel value, then we must implement or own `merge` method, which could be implemented like something like this: `return (!containsKey(key) ? super.merge(key, value, remappingFunction) : put(key, null));`.

Comment: you have some minor compilation problems btw in your snippet, but the bigger problem is that you got really lucky to see the correct output for the dataset that the OP provided. For example, add one more student `Student stud4 = new Student("Eugene", Arrays.asList("Math"));`...

Comment: this solution would work only when you are sure that the subjects are one of a kind or if they are repeated across students, they are evenly repeated; only in such a case the merger `(t, u) -> null` would work, you might also explain why exactly it works the way it does too. And of course defining the merger as `(t, u) -> null` when `t` and `u` already exist in the scope is *extremely* misleading; may be better `(left, right) -> null`

Comment: @Eugene You're right, I didn't think about that. I need to work on that merger. Let me address this problem.

Comment: Might be simpler to replace the second stream operation by a Collection operation, i.e. `Set<Student> list = new HashSet<>(/* first stream op */.values()); list.remove(Student.SENTINEL_VALUE);`

Answer (score 2):

Another solution. Looks kind of similar to Eugene.

```
Stream.of(stud1, stud2, stud3, stud4)
    .flatMap( s -> s.getSubjects().stream().map( subj -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>( subj, s ) ) )
    .collect( Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey) )

    .entrySet().stream()
    .filter( e -> e.getValue().size() == 1 )
    .map( e -> e.getValue().get(0).getValue().getName() )
    .collect( Collectors.toSet() );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do it in a simpler way as :

```
Stream<Student> studentStream = Stream.of(stud1, stud2, stud3);

// collect all the unique subjects into a Set
Set<String> uniqueSubjects = studentStream
        .flatMap(st -> st.getSubjects().stream()
                .map(subj -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(st.getName(), subj)))
         // subject to occurence count map
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getValue() == 1) // occurs only once
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)  // Q ->  map keys are anyway unique 
        .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // ^^ ... any way to optimise this?(keySet)

// amongst the students, filter those which have any unique subject in their subject list
List<String> studentsStudyingUniqueSubjects = studentStream
        .filter(stud -> stud.getSubjects().stream()
                .anyMatch(uniqueSubjects::contains))
        .map(Student::getName)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Indeed, I meant the count when grouped by subject. :) Updated, thanks. By the way, feel free to edit any such stupid mistakes if you're willing to.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most readable solution, but here you go:

```
studentStream.flatMap(st -> st.getSubjects().stream().map(subj -> new SimpleEntry<>(st.getName(), subj)))
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                     Entry::getValue,
                     x -> {
                         List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                         list.add(x.getKey());
                         return list;
                     },
                     (left, right) -> {
                         left.addAll(right);
                         return left;
                     }
                 ))
                 .entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .filter(x -> x.getValue().size() == 1)
                 .map(Entry::getValue)
                 .flatMap(List::stream)
                 .distinct()
                 .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Comment: You reinvented the `groupingBy` collector.